# How to get jar class is coming from

Tags: java, eclipse, api, plugins, log4j2

I am currently working on an API for a server software so users can extend my software by programming plugins for it instead of modifying the software themselves, and allow other users without programming knowledge to easily change the software by adding these plugins. So far, everything is working fine. But, I am running into a problem with configuration.

You see, each plugin has a plugin.yml file stored with these 4 attributes:
Main: The main class is stored here
Name: This is where the plugin name is stored
Version: This is where the plugin version is stored
Author: This is where the plugin author is stored

Now, in order for the plugin to print something to the console, they use a function called: this.getServer().getLogger().info("MESSAGE); (They extend another class for plugins, thats why they use "this" instead of another class to log)

But, I do not have any idea on how to get which plugin is which when they are calling the function. I have a ArrayList of PluginSessions which event handlers use to cycle through to run Event Functions.

My solution is to get the jar from which a class is being called so I can then get the plugin.yml from there. But, I have NO idea on how to get that, I have tried using Class.forName(); and some other code. But because the class is non-existent within the jar/project running the code, It will throw a ClassNotFoundException.

Does anyone here know how to get the jar from which a class is coming from without using Class.forName()? Thanks! -Trent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at `Class.getResource`.

If you call MyClass.getResource("plugin.yml") (or "/plugin.yml" with leading slash, I forget) you get back a file URL pointing to the plugin.yml file in the same jar as MyClass. (Or `null` if the path is wrong or the jar doesn't contain a "plugin.yml" file.) You can then open an InputStream to that resource. In a plugin framework you may want to use `myPluginInstance.getClass().getResource`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! Now I can finally get plugin info outside of my plugin session class! :D

Answer (score 0):

Assuming jar for **'PluginSessions'** is already added in you **classpath**  by eclipse then you can try the following trick -

1. Select/highlight **PluginSessions** by double clicking on it
2. Now press **CTRL+SHIFT+T**
3. A dialog named **Open Type** is appeared. Here you found from where the **PluginSessions** class is coming from. If you have more than one jar containing **PluginSessions** class than you have a list of them.

To benefited from this **CTRL+SHIFT+T**  trick you need to add all of your jar need by the project to be added in your `classpath`.

Comment: This is not the answer I was wanting. I said I was wanting to be able to get the jar a class was calling from (A plugin) Through the code so I could get the the plugin.yml from the jar and get its name.